# Can I Use Superuser Permissions To See All Apps Currently Running

Tags: android

I want to make an app that essentially mines every bit of data that it can from a phone for a university research project. For this, I will need to know what apps are open (all of them) and it seems that, as of API 21, just listing the current app is a rather tricky endeavor. If the user grants superuser access    requested via:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER">
</permission>
```

can I get around Googles obvious attempts to make it harder to get even tiny bits of information out of the phone. Or have they gone as far as making superuser access not so super anymore?

Also, I know I can just root the device, but this application will be installed on other peoples devices (data will be stored locally). As I understand it, non rooted devices can still grant superuser access upon permission (or via toast message if permissions are not listed in the manifest)

EDIT: apparently, as of android 5.0, SU is no longer available to non rooted devices...

Thanks

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28539808/unknown-permission-android-permission-access-superuser-in-package-com-powervr-pv

Comment: I don't think this would have any effect on a non-rooted device.

Comment: So you cant even access superuser anymore? Ugh....